# Programatically Create Excel Sheets from different templates using a Addin

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am developing an `Excel Addin` that is able to fetch data from our database.Instead of dumping the data directly , I would like to have the data presented in a nice format. I have got our local VBA expert to develop a templates for the same  since there can be multiple sheets all of which can have different formats.

It is while adding the worksheet that I am stuck at.

```
string TemplateFileLocation  = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
if(File.Exists(fileName)) 
{
    Worksheet newWorkSheet  = (WorkSheet)Globals.ThisAddin.Aplication.Worksheets.Add(Missing.Value,Missing.Value,1,TemplateFileLocation);
}
```

The code crashes while it hits this location.
The Error code returned is : 0x800A03EC

I have verified that the path to the template file is correct.

Each of these templates have only one work sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using OfficeOpenXml;

//Create a stream of .xlsx file contained within my project using reflection
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("EPPlusTest.templates.VendorTemplate.xlsx");            

//EPPlusTest = Namespace/Project
//templates = folder
//VendorTemplate.xlsx = file

//ExcelPackage has a constructor that only requires a stream.
  ExcelPackage pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(stream);
```